# Meaning IPTables command output for 3g connection

Tags: iptables, android, 3g

Can somebody explain me the meaning of this output of iptables command in Android running 3g connection?[image]

[image: Output IPTables command on Android device]

I forgot Chain INPUT

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1522 packets, 486K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 9579 2150K bw_INPUT   all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
 9579 2150K firewall   all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
 9579 2150K fw_INPUT   all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind elaborating on the question? What's being show is just iptables / firewall rules. What specifically are you concerned with?

Comment: I'd like to know if firewall in my Android (with these settings)accepts every type of incoming packets from any host or drops some incoing packets; i'd like to know if firewall does the same thing for outgoing packets(is it the chain output, right?). Also i'd like to know what "chain firewall" means

Comment: Your main chain output and forward are wide open. Chain input allows anything on bw_INPUT, firewall and fw_INPUT to the OS. bw_INPUT is set to allow anything. Firewall is set to allow anything from mobile. fw_INPUT has no rules applied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two other question: what is the meaning of bw_Input and fw_input? So , the device can accept and receive any packets ?

Comment: And wht is the meaning of REJECT with quota in bw_costly_ccmni0 table ?

Comment: Sorry, I could not tell what those are for. Likely some google naming convention for internal services that I'm not familiar.

Comment: Ok, in google it seems ther's no way to find this type of REJECT. Anyawy, thank you for the answer :)